# How can I limit my entire regular expression to 254 characters?

Tags: regex, email

I've got a basic email regular expression, however I have a requirement that the it also validates the length of characters is not more that 254 (as per email standards?

How would I make sure that it does not match emails longer than 254 characters long?

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

http://regexr.com/3fsck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `^(?=.{0,254}$)` at the start:

```
^(?=.{0,254}$)[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-+]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

Demo: http://regexr.com/3fscq

Comment: That is, assuming the language or text editor in use supports lookaheads. (Many do.)